# Can an Android app interact with another app?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to be able to tap the statusbar and the contents in the displayed app to be scrolled up to the top.
Is it technically possible that an app intercept my tap and send the appropriate command to the active app? I have noticed for example that AntTek quick settings shows a drop-down window when swiping down from statusbar. While using the app I did also notice that even by just tapping the statusbar (before beginning to move the finger down), the app seems to already interact with the touch as it dims the screen brightness in preparation to display it's "window" (sorry I use the MS Windows term), so clearly a statusbar tap CAN be sensed by an app.
Starting from this, I wonder if such an app could then send a message to the active program telling it to scroll up.
Is that possible? And if yes, the message must be customized to a particular app (let's say the browser as the most important) or is it standardized so the apps speak the same language between themselves?
I am not a programmer so answers with codesamples might be less helpful than a plain english explanation. Finding out that is possible would lead rather to pursuing a programmer to implement the idea rather than starting to develop it myself.
Thanks :-)

Comment: hi. Not answering but, just throwing ideas. Maybe you can manage to ge the Layout hierarchy of the current app (I don't know how), but if you do, it could be a simple exercise of navigating down the tree using `getChild...` methods and scrolling the scrolable types such as ScrollView, ListView, GridView, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an XPosed-module which seems to do exactly what you want.

To use XPosed-modules, you'll need to root your phone and install the XPosed-framework.

The XPosed-module is called "Statusbar Scroll to Top" and its repository can be found here:
http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.mohammadag.statusbarscrolltotop

This will work for almost all app-lists, but for example won't work for browser-content.

If you want to scroll to the top of the page in a browser, then you'll probably do best to get a browser which can do that on its own. (For example Habit Browser has it built-in and respective plugins are available for Firefox.)

Comment: Thanks, that looks interesting. I will test it next time I use the tablet.

Comment: where exactly is scroll to top configured in habit browser? and where do i have to tap? :)

Comment: @CostinGușă Yeah, sorry, Habit Browser is a tiny bit complicated. One place, where you can reach it in the default setup is if you touch the left edge of your screen and then drag to the right a little bit, until a wheel of options opens up around your finger. There, drag your finger to the top-centered option and release your touch. But you can configure stuff like that completely, if you want to. You could for example put it on the tap of a button in the little Button-ribbon. And then maybe even put that ribbon at the top of the screen, so that it's similar to the statusbar-tap...

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. HiroMacro and Frep can do this, but it requires root. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.prohiro.macro&hl=en
(how do they simulate mouse and keyboard interactions on other applications? i have no clue :/ anyone?)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it technically possible that an app intercept my tap and send the appropriate command to the active app?

No. One app cannot send fake input to another app, for security reasons.

Comment: But can it send legitimate messages? Do they have a communication protocol? And if not, can this security wall be broken by running the app as root?

Comment: @CostinGușă: Apps do not have a communications protocol covering your scenario by default. *Possibly* there are ways to handle this via root.

Comment: HiroMacro does this, so its definitely possible. needs root though.

Answer (score 0):

An android app comprises of several activities. Each activity display a GUI that allows the user to perform a specific task. To take the user from one activity to another, app must use an Intent to define our app’s intent to do something.

An intent can be explicit in order to start a specific component (a specific Activity instance) or implicit in order to start any component that can handle the intended action.

[Interacting one app to other app in android](http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/16526a76-eaa7-440c-b96b-9222f2f6d776/Interacting%20one%20app%20to%20other%20app%20in%20android)

[google docs link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/index.html)